# Fetching image using API in Flutter

Tags: flutter, rest

The following `ProgressEvent$` object was thrown resolving an image codec:

> [object ProgressEvent]

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

```
final picture=user['picture']['thumbnail'];
return ListTile(
   title: Text(firstName+' '+lastName),
   subtitle: Text(email),
   leading: ClipRRect(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
       child: Image.network(picture),
         ),
   );
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you've been looking for in the minimum viable way.

Source code:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: NewHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class NewHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<NewHomePage> createState() => _NewHomePageState();
}

class _NewHomePageState extends State<NewHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.separated(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              dense: true,
              leading: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                child: Image.network(
                  "https://picsum.photos/${index * 50}",
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              title: Text("Title: $index"),
              subtitle: Text("Subtitle: $index"),
              trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
              onTap: () {},
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return const Divider(height: 1, thickness: 1);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```